# Force link to look not visited using CSS

Tags: css, visited

Is there a way to use CSS to make a given link appear as it is not visited, even if it has already been visited?

I know you can do this by explicitly setting the same color for the visited and non-visited links. But is it possible to do this without hardcoding the color of the visited links? Just telling the CSS to color them using the same color as the non-visited links, whatever that may be.

The reason for this is that I want to Rickroll a friend.

Comment: Well, you could just define the `a` tag like: `a { color:#0000FF }`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without hard-coding the color?

Comment: Hard coding the color? It only needs to be done once, so it shouldn't be that tedious.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a solution that works independently of the base stylesheet. I don't know what is the color of the non-visited links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution using Javascript is to get the color using the `getComputedStyle` function. This takes advantage of the fact that the `getComputedStyle` function always pretends that the link is colored as if it hadn't been visited (as an anti-fingerprinting measure).

```
// Set the colot of a link to the color of a non-visited link
var link = document.getElementById("TheID");
var color = window.getComputedStyle(link).getPropertyValue("color");
link.style.color = color;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage the [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) property:

```
a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Another option is to use [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

```
a {
  color: red !important;  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's working.. https://jsbin.com/cizuwej/edit?html,css

Comment: When I tried this it made the link look black instead of making it look blue.

Comment: Try setting `body`'s color to red, instead of setting `a`.

Comment: `body {
  color: red;  
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}`

Comment: At this point I feel like we might as well just do `a { color : red }`. But I'm curious if there is a solution that doesn't need to hardcode the color.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without hardcoding the color. CSS `visited` tags were meant to be inaccessible from the start.  For example, the Javascript method `window.getComputedStyle` method will literally *lie* and always return the value of the non-`:visited` color. Read the docs for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: Hey! Just found something else. You can do `a { color: red !important;  }`. No `:visited` selector. Edited the answer above ^

Comment: Actually, the getComputedStyle returning the non-visited color is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.